# db derby StartNetworkServer

Tags: database, derby

I have problem with starting derby server.
My derby version: db-derby-10.11.1.1

I followed this tutorial:
http://db.apache.org/derby/papers/DerbyTut/ns_intro.html

but after typing: startNetworkServer.bat there is no response:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/bo1tgfj8gf2533i/derby_issue.PNG?dl=0

Could you help me? 
Maybe there is some problem with my localhost?
I think that i install Derby correctly because after typing: java org.apache.derby.tools.sysinfo
I got some result

regards

Comment: Try changing the first line of startNetworkServer.bat from "@echo off" to "@echo on" and then run startNetworkServer.bat again and post the results.

Comment: I had the same problem! If you are using Java 7 or 8 you don't need to install derby, because it comes within the jdk. The following video was the solution for me: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K8lAlotLuiE

Answer (score 8):

The bug is in the localization (for me in *cs* localization) and the derby server does not print exceptions by default.

Workaround: Under windows in the console run the following commands:

```
set "DERBY_OPTS=-Duser.language=en -Dderby.drda.debug=true" 
startNetworkServer.bat
```

The first line adds two options for `java/derby`. First option to change the local language to *en* and the second one enables printing debug messages to the console.
The second line runs the server (add path if needed).

Another workaround is adding the missing localization key `DRDA_MissingNetworkJar.S` to file `org\apache\derby\loc\drda\messages_cs.properties` inside `derbynet.jar`.

Comment: Thank you! This helped for Russian locale, too

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with using derby in 1.8.0_45 but changing the DERBY_HOME back to 1.8.0_31 solved it.

Answer (score 0):

This may occurs due to different Java version in your local.
Try using jdk 11. It works fine and networkserver gets started.
Please check out different versions so that you may get solution.