# Trying to connect Derby db in Intellij IDEA

Tags: sql, intellij-idea, local, derby

As title says: Intellij IDEA 16.2, Win7, Derby, trying to connect each other.
Dont know what to add here, but this editor of text wants some more information from me. Help me pls)
[img3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcaF7.jpg)
[img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRcVd.jpg)

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -11
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1931)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.getDatabaseName(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.getPropertyInfo(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver.getPropertyInfo(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.database.remote.jdbc.impl.RemoteDriverImpl.getPropertyInfo(RemoteDriverImpl.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:324)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:276)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:253)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:162)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:227)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:179)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy135.getPropertyInfo(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil.invokeRemote(RemoteUtil.java:169)
    at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil.access$300(RemoteUtil.java:36)
    at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil$RemoteInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteUtil.java:274)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy136.getPropertyInfo(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.database.view.ui.DatabaseDriverPropertiesPanel.lambda$refreshAdvancedProperties$1(DatabaseDriverPropertiesPanel.java:195)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$2.run(ApplicationImpl.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Derby on Intellij](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29850005/derby-on-intellij)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Omg, my mistake was in shut-downed derby. =|
I have a problem with localization also.
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27013886/db-derby-startnetworkserver)
This one helped me with understanding what my problem is.